# why can't I submit an empty textbox to the server

Tags: html, forms, bootstrap-4

when I click the 'save new post' button and the title and body content are provided then the action of sending a request is successfull, but if I leave one field blank, than the request isn't even made.
this is my code:

```
<form action="/create-post" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="post-title" class="text-muted mb-1"><small>Title</small></label>
    <input required name="title" id="post-title" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-title" type="text" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="post-body" class="text-muted mb-1"><small>Body Content</small></label>
    <textarea required name="body" id="post-body" class="body-content tall-textarea form-control" type="text"></textarea>
  </div>
  
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Save New Post</button>
</form>
```

And this is what I get when I leave a field blank:
[form behavor after submitting empty field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXYVr.png)

in the image, *'Compila questo campo'* just means *'Fill in this field'*

Edit:
thank you for reminding me that it’s because of the **required** field, but then why is that in this example i can't submit if the **title** field is empty but can if the **body** is empty?

```
<form class="mt-3" action="/post/<%= post._id %>/edit" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="post-title" class="text-muted mb-1"><small>Title</small></label>
  <input required name="title" value="<%= post.title %>" id="post-title" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-title" type="text" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="post-body" class="text-muted mb-1"><small>Body Content</small></label>
  <textarea required name="body" id="post-body" class="body-content tall-textarea form-control" type="text"><%= post.body %>
  </textarea>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
```

Note that this is a ejs template, so that's why it as <% and <%=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have required attribute both of your inputs. So you can't submit this form in this way.

[See here for details](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)

For example in this example you can submit the form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The button type attribute</h1>

<form action="#" method="get">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
  <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
  <button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

But in this example you can't:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The button type attribute</h1>

<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" required><br><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" required><br><br>
  <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
  <button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that helped me; so why is that in the second example I can submit even if the body content (that is required) is empty?

Comment: Can you inspect your body content data from developer tools on browser? And show us what is its value. Maybe a space data or anything can be in it.

Comment: Yes that was the reason, thank you for notice it

Answer (score 0):

You explicitly said that the user was [`required` to fill in a value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required).

Don't do that if the field is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `<input>` and `<textarea>` tags have `required` attribute. Remove that attribute if you want to make them optional.

Answer (score 0):

You are using required attribute with textbox and text area.

The required attribute is a boolean attribute.

When present, it specifies that an input field must be filled out before submitting the form.

This is client side (browser side validation).

[Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)